# Portable air conditioner exhaust through door

Tags: humidity

Dryer & washer outside in a room w/out access to window. Can portable air conditioner be vented/hose used through door when needed?

Comment: Yes, but not very efficiently.  What else is in this room?  Would it suffice to keep the door open and use a box fan?

Comment: I think that is probably the best idea since this is a temporary rent house.  Thank You so much everyone for your advice!!

Answer (score 1):

To quote from Consumer Reports,

> Unlike a window air conditioner, all the mechanical parts of a
>   portable air conditioner are sitting in the room you’re trying to
>   cool. This contributes to the noise and less-than-capable cooling, as
>   the portable unit is using conditioned air from the room to cool the
>   condenser and exhausts the hot air out an ungainly exhaust hose that
>   resembles a dryer vent. That creates negative pressure causing
>   unconditioned warm air from surrounding rooms or outdoors to be drawn
>   into the room you’re trying keep cool

So unless the rest of your house is cool, in which case a box fan will do the job, you're not going to get much cooling in your laundry room.

In sum: yes, you can install a portable unit, and it will operate. No, it won't do much good.

.

Comment: Downvoters are requested to give a reason.

Comment: I did not down vote but the OP wants to vent the heat this may not be the most efficient setup for a window AC unit but it will work and the room will cool with the amount of heat exhausted.

Comment: We actually have a similar situation with a portable AC in our bedroom. We normally keep the door mostly closed and to get around the vacuum issue, we open the top part of the window that the AC is being vented through enough so it's not pulling a vacuum in the rest of the house. The open window doesn't have much of a effect on the room coldness because it gets plenty darn cold still. Most of it gets sucked right down to the AC.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other convenient place to exhaust the hot air the door could be used. I would look at dog doors IE cutting a hole and adding a flange and put the hole in the center area that a dog door would go. If you plan on making a panel to crack the door open and blow the hot air outside that would work but not as well as through the door. Remember the system is blowing hot air out so there will need to be a place for fresh air to enter.